# Troubleshooting Issues with app.open() Function - Unable to Launch Application

Tags: java, android, windows, sikuli

When utilizing the app.open() function, I encounter a situation where the result is [-1:C:\Users<path>\xyz.exe ()] C:\Users<path>\xyz.exe. Despite ensuring the accuracy of the provided path, the application fails to launch through app.open(). What could be potential causes for this issue?

Application must be launch using app.open()